MySQL get all weekend days between two dates
I'm trying to calculate how many weekend days passed between two dates.
  SELECT DISTINCT
    start_date AS fr_date,
    end_date AS to_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%a') AS wd_fr,
    DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%a') AS wd_to,
    (

        FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, end_date) / 7) * 2

        + IF(DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%w') IN (0, 6), 1, 0)
        + IF(DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%w') IN (0, 6), 1, 0)

        + CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%w') <= DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%w')
                 AND DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%w') IN (0, 6)
            THEN CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%w') IN (0, 6) THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS weekend_days
FROM table
WHERE end_date > start_date
ORDER BY start_date DESC;

I tried using GPT but it didn't bring any value.
Date format is yyyy-mm-dd. Code sometimes doubles Sundays or ignoring Saturdays and I feel like I got stuck up to this point

You are very close to your solution. You are missing small things. By looking at your SQL, you are trying to calculate the number of weekend days between two dates.
Here is the revised code:
SELECT DISTINCT
  start_date AS fr_date,
  end_date AS to_date,
  (
    FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, end_date) / 7) * 2
    + IF(WEEKDAY(start_date) >= 5, 1, 0)
    + IF(WEEKDAY(end_date) >= 5, 1, 0)
  ) AS weekend_days
FROM table
WHERE end_date > start_date
ORDER BY start_date DESC;

I removed the DATE_FORMAT functions, as they are not necessary, Instead, I am using WEEKDAY function, which returns the day of the week as an integer (0- Monday, 1 = Tuesday, ... and 6 = Sunday)
I simplified the query by counting the weekend days. I am adding 1 to the count and if it's Sunday or Saturday will return 5 and 6.
I also removed the CASE statement, as it is not needed with the new logic.

Using the fact that 1900-01-01 is Monday. I would try something like this:
SELECT DISTINCT
    start_date,
    end_date,
    (
       ((datediff(end_date, "1900-01-01") + 1) DIV 7)    -- Saturdays from 1900-01-01 to end_date
     - ((datediff(start_date, "1900-01-01") + 1) DIV 7)  -- Saturdays from 1900-01-01 to start_date
     + (datediff(end_date, "1900-01-01") DIV 7)          -- Sundays from 1900-01-01 to end_date
     - (datediff(start_date, "1900-01-01") DIV 7)        -- Sundays from 1900-01-01 to start_date
    ) as weekend_days
FROM your_table;

